# MSP430 Interrupt routines with msp-gcc won't compile

Tags: gcc, interrupt, msp430

I am using the newest CCS with MSP-GCC compiler. The following code

```
#pragma vector=USCI_A1_VECTOR
__interrupt void USCI_A1_ISR(void)
{...isr}
```

which is the newest officially supported method by TI of declaring ISR-s is not working, I get the following complier messages:

```
warning: ignoring #pragma vector  [-Wunknown-pragmas]
#pragma vector=USCI_A1_VECTOR
^
error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'void'
__interrupt void USCI_A1_ISR(void)
```

I have also tried different methods, like:

```
interrupt(USCI_A1_VECTOR) USCI_A1_ISR(void) {  //code goes here}
```

which gives the error:

```
c:/ti/ccsv6/ccs_base/msp430/include_gcc/msp430f5529.h:5328:33: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before '(' token
#define USCI_A1_VECTOR          (47)                     /* 0xFFDC USCI A1 Receive/Transmit */
                                ^
../uart_printf.c:40:11: note: in expansion of macro 'USCI_A1_VECTOR'
interrupt(USCI_A1_VECTOR) USCI_A1_ISR(void)
          ^
```

This seems to work though:

```
__attribute__((interrupt(USCI_A1_VECTOR)))
void USCI_A1_ISR(void){ //code goes here }
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5):

There is no C standard for interrupt routine declaration (a real pitty). Each compiler has it's own way to do it.

TI relased RedHat MSP430 GCC last month and had no time to take a look into it. But for the old MSPGCC branch your last example should be valid.

MSPGCC also provides an include file for better compiler interop:

```
#include <isr_compat.h>

ISR(USCI_A1, USCI_A1_ISR)
{
    // Code goes here
}
```

**Important:** remove the '_VECTOR' tail from the ISR name

Take a look at the **isr_compat.h** file. It is actually designed to work with all compilers on the market. Maybe it's a good idea to borrow it into your project, if there's nothing similar on your compiler suite.